# Only raw audio data broadcast without using mic or speaker

Tags: android, webrtc, live, android-broadcast, agora.io

I am only able to broadcast audio alone using mic and speaker, and if I use setExternalAudioSource method, then the broadcast encounter with some heavy unwanted noise. I just want to broadcast the raw audio data alone without using mic, speaker and unwanted noise.

```
 private val PERMISSION_REQ_ID_RECORD_AUDIO = 22
private var mRtcEngine: RtcEngine? = null// Tutorial Step 1
private val mRtcEventHandler = object : IRtcEngineEventHandler() { // Tutorial Step 1

    override fun onUserOffline(uid: Int, reason: Int) { // Tutorial Step 4
        //runOnUiThread { onRemoteUserLeft(uid, reason) }
    }

    override fun onUserMuteAudio(uid: Int, muted: Boolean) { // Tutorial Step 6
        // runOnUiThread { onRemoteUserVoiceMuted(uid, muted) }
    }
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO, PERMISSION_REQ_ID_RECORD_AUDIO)) {
        createRtcChannel()
    }

}

fun checkSelfPermission(permission: String, requestCode: Int): Boolean {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                arrayOf(permission),
                requestCode)
        return false
    }
    return true
}

private fun createRtcChannel() {
    initializeAgoraEngine()     // Tutorial Step 1
    joinChannel()
}

private fun initializeAgoraEngine() {
    try {
        mRtcEngine = RtcEngine.create(this, getString(R.string.agora_app_id), mRtcEventHandler)
        //set the channel as live broadcast mode
        mRtcEngine?.setChannelProfile(Constants.CHANNEL_PROFILE_LIVE_BROADCASTING)
        mRtcEngine?.setClientRole(Constants.CLIENT_ROLE_BROADCASTER)
    } catch (e: Exception) {

    }
}

private fun joinChannel() {
    mRtcEngine?.joinChannel(null, "voiceDemoChannel1", "Extra Optional Data", 0) // if you do not specify the uid, we will generate the uid for you

    val payload = IOUtils.toByteArray(assets.openFd("ringtone.mp3").createInputStream())

    mRtcEngine?.setExternalAudioSource(
            true,      
            8000,     
            1     );

    mRtcEngine?.pushExternalAudioFrame(
            payload,
            1000
    )

}
```

Is this possible using agora or is there any alternative to it?

Answer (score 0):

Reasons can cause the noise:

1. Your source audio PCM samples are noisy by themselves
2. Engine bugs
3. The sample rate you set is wrong

For the first one, you can check your PCM samples directly. For the 2nd, as there are already many people using, it's rare to be true. So I woulld suguest you to check the sample rate if you are sure your source PCM samples are good.

Also, you can set up the APM option before you join channel to enable audio enhancement for external source, by

```
setParameters("{\"che.audio.override_apm\":true}")
```